# Sull'espressione "fare repulisti"

Tags: word-usage

Repulisti è un latinismo che è sopravvissuto e si è bene adattato al linguaggio contemporaneo soprattutto nell'espressione "fare repulisti":

***[Repulisti](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/repulisti/)*** s. m. [voce lat. dei Salmi (42, 2: quare me repulisti? «perché mi hai respinto?»; 43, 10, ecc.):

> - perfetto indic. (nel lat. classico reppulisti) del verbo repellĕre «respingere», ravvicinato scherz. a pulire]. – Nell’espressione fam. e scherz. fare repulisti, portare via, fare sparire tutto da un luogo, quasi lasciandolo pulito, spec. rubando o mangiando.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repulisti&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepulisti%3B%2Cc0): repulisti.

C'è un motivo per cui questa parola è rimasta ben presente nel linguaggio contemporaneo, come ad esempio l'uso da parte di uno scrittore famoso o l'uso giornalistico?

Answer (score 2):

Ho trovato un paio di esempi in Google Books. 
"Il malmantile riacquistato" del fiorentino Lorenzo Lippi (1606-1665),
da "Raccolta dei più celebri poemi eroico-comici italiani con cenni biografici su i respettivi autori", Canto settimo, https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=iwUtAAAAYAAJ&q=repulisti#v=snippet&q=repulisti&f=false:

*voltossi a' dieci pan da Meo provvisti,*

*E in un momento fece repulisti*

"Bertoldo, Bertoldino e Cacasenno: poema giocoso" (1670), da Giulio Cesare Croce e Adriano Banchieri,
https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=7No-AAAAIAAJ&dq=bertoldo+bertoldino+e+cacasenno+repulisti&q=repulisti#v=snippet&q=repulisti&f=false:

*Com'ebbe il confortino ch'io vi accenno,*

*E fece repulisti in un momento*

Comment: Quindi, l'espressione era già in uso nel Seicento

Comment: Secondo lo Zingarelli, che dà la prima data di attestazione per ogni lemma, addirittura dal 1521.

Comment: @DaG: La citazione del Bibbiena sembra essere del 1513.

Answer (score 2):

Il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00853.jpg) spiega come questo termine entrò a far parte della lingua italiana:

> =  Lat. *repulisti*
>     (seconda  pers.  sing.  del  perf.  indic.,  di 
>   *repellĕre*  ‘ respingere ’),  tratto  dal versetto  2  del  salmo  42 ‘ Quia  tu  es,  Deus,  fortitudo  mea,  quare  me  repulisti?  ’ 
>   (‘ Poiché  tu  sei,  o  Dio,  la  mia  fortezza,  perché  mi  hai  re­spinto? ’)  e  accostato  popolarmente  al  signif.  di  ‘ ripulire ’.

Quindi, popolarmente si associava il vocabolo "repulisti", presente in questo versetto del salmo 42, al verbo "ripulire" e in modo ironico o scherzoso, come si vede in questo stesso [dizionario](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00852.jpg), si cominciarono a usare espressioni come "fare un *repulisti  me  Do­mine*" e "cantare *Domine repulisti*", come in questa citazione di [Pietro Aretino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pietro_Aretino)

> In casa  non c’è altro che madonna vec­chia  con  la fanticella  che  la  governa  amalata,  e  il  resto  de la  famiglia  ha  fatto  un  repulisti  me  Domine

e in quest'altra di [Bartolomeo Corsini](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartolomeo_Corsini)

> Non vider già, ch'i ladri  di  buon'ora  /  con  uncinate  mani  avean  cantato / ‘ Domine repulisti ’ in ogni lato

o semplicemente "fare repulisti", "fare il repulisti" oppure "fare un repulisti" (a volte scritto "ripulisti" o "repuliste"), come in questo passo da [*La calandria*](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Calandria) di [Bernardo Dovizi, detto il Bibbiena](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernardo_Dovizi_da_Bibbiena)

> Io  faceva  pensiero  di  andarmene  invi­sibile  alle  casse  di  certi  pigoloni  avaracci,  a’  quali  non  si trarrebbe  un  grosso  delle  mani  con  le  tanaglie  di  Nicodemo,  e  quivi  volevo  fare  un  ripulisti  di  tal  sorte  che  non rimanessi  loro  un  marcio  quartino

e in quest'altro di Pietro Aretino

> Si  dèe perdonare  ad  uno  che,  incitato  dal  giuoco,  fa  il repulisti alle  tattare  e  di  casa  e  della  moglie  e  degli  amici  e  degli attenenti.